# Transfer EE site to GoDaddy

Tags: ee2, database, godaddy

First off, I need to start with the fact that I cannot STAND GoDaddy... However, I had an old hosted account from 2002 on there and decided to use it as a dev playground to try some stuff out. I had a local site already function running on WAMP on a Windows machine. When I went to transfer the site to GoDaddy, I have yet, (3 days deep), been able to get it running. Here is what I have done:

1. Created the Sub Domain (dev)
2. Created the Database in MySQL
3. Exported the database from my local MySQL
4. Imported the previously exported database into the newly created database
5. Placed the system folder in the webroot (due to GD being persnickity)
6. Placed the rest of the site in the dev folder for the Sub Domain dev.domain.com
7. Modified my index.php and admin.php files to reflect the new locations
8. Updated the database file to reflect the new information:

   ```
   $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = 'dbname.db.acct-number.hostedresource.com';
   $db['expressionengine']['username'] = 'username';
   $db['expressionengine']['password'] = 'password';
   $db['expressionengine']['database'] = 'database';
   ```

However, I keep getting the following on admin and site:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found
```

So to verify I had the connection strings correct, I copied the dbtest.php file to the dev folder and ran it after changing the following fields:

```
$hostname   = "dbname.db.acct-number.hostedresource.com";
$username   = "username";
$password   = "password";
$db_name    = "database";
```

When I hit this page, I am given the following:

```
A connection was established to your database server
Your database was selected.
```

I am running out of ideas and GoDaddy support has yet to respond to a ticket from 3 days ago. I guess I am lost as to why dbtest hits fine, but the admin and site say a connection could not be established. (This is the message I receive when I turn on the debug to 1.

Comment: I looks like the `config.php` wasn't loaded. Please, check the `system` path on the files `index.php` and `admin.php`

Comment: @RobsonSobral thanks for the suggestion. I output an echo for $system_path on both files in the section for /* Resolve the system path for increased reliability to verify the location, and it output correctly.

Comment: Also, when I throw in <code>echo file_exists(BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter'.EXT);
 return;</code>, it returns 1 (true), so the paths must be correct.

Comment: I was able to fix this by re-exporting the database and re-importing the database. It looked as though it did not export completely before. I also had to rename some tables that were case sensitive for some reason.

Comment: Keep in mind, there have also been reports that GoDaddy flags some ee system files as malware. Namely:
/system/codeigniter/system/core/Security.php

Comment: ^^^^  Another reason why GoDaddy has become a joke in the hosting lands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BrianMallett was able to resolve this by re-importing his database as it did not properly import to GoDaddy the first time.